# fadeToggle next element in on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following code to show the next element in the dom on click, I would like to convert this same code into something I could use for a simple hover event.  Does jQuery have a simple method to do something like this or should I be using `.bind()` to `mouseover` and `mouseout` events?  I know this should be simple, I am probably just not thinking clearly.

```
$('#el').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $prevEl =   $(this).parent().find('.prev-el');
    $prevEl.fadeToggle();
});
```

One thing to mention is I would like the `$prevEl` to stay visible after hovering the triggering `#el` element.  What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you in advance,

DT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$('#el').mouseover(...` instead of `$('#el').click(...`, but you should use `fadeIn` instead of `fadeToggle` when you're using `mouseover`:

```
$('#el').mouseover(function(e) {
    var $prevEl = $(this).parent().find('.prev-el');
    $prevEl.fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eXjTb/3/

If you want it to fade back out on mouseout, though, use `.hover` as a shorthand way to combine the two and keep the `fadeToggle`:

```
$('#el').hover(function(e) {
    var $prevEl = $(this).parent().find('.prev-el');
    $prevEl.fadeToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eXjTb/2/

Comment: I forgot to mention I would like the $prevEl to stay visible after hovering the triggering #el element.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Thanks for your time and help on this, this is what we need but we will have clickable elements in the $prevEl element so it needs to stay visible on hover and once hovered out it should fade out again.  I hope this is making sense.

Comment: So just add a mouseout event to the prev-el: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eXjTb/4/ -- either way, your original question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$('#el').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.prev-el').fadeIn();
});
```

By the way, you can use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead of `.parent().find(...)`  (depending on your html)